# How to get start- and endpositions of HTML tags in Java?

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

In my Java application, I need to analyze HTML. Until now, I used JSoup and it worked very well. But now, I need to get the cleaned text from a HTML String, AND, additionally, the positions of the tags that were removed. For example, if I have

```
Some HTML <b id="boldtext">text</b>
```

the needed output would be

```
Some HTML text
```

and the information, that there was a b-tag from the position 10 to 14 (I need the position of the tags as if there were no tags there) and the tag had the id "boldtext".

(I hope I could make clear what I need, I'm not so good at explaining -  it's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953451/remove-html-tags-and-get-start-end-indices-of-marked-down-text) question except I also need the attributes of the found tags and it's Java, not Python)

I would like to do this using JSoup, but didn't found a way to do it(if there is one, please tell me!). Implementingmy own algorythm also didn't work well, it was hard to understand and caused many bugs. So, what is a good way to get the required information? Is there a way to do this using JSoup? Do I need a different library? Any help appreciated!

**Edit:**I'm gonna try to make more clear what I need. In the above example, I need the HTML-clean text and the information which part of the remaining text was bold. I need the start and end positions, but the HTML tags are removed later, so they mustn't be counted when searching for the right position.

The perfect output would be a list of objects, which each contain information about one tag (and by tag I mean an opening an a closing tag belonging together): tag type (e.g. "b", "quote", etc.), tag content (without HTML), attributes and the start and end position of the tag. Again, the positions need to stay valid when I remove the tags from the tag! After the tags were cleaned, the app still needs to know that "text" was bold, and not that before removing the tags, the beginning of the closing tag was at 31, because while removing the tags, the correct closing position moved 17 chars to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to find and replace all the HTML tags with empty string. The regular expression matcher also can return the index of matched groups.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author user
 *
 */
public class HTMLProcessor {

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String HTML_PATTERN = "<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";
/**
 * 
 */
public HTMLProcessor() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(HTML_PATTERN);        
}

public String Process(String htmlString) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Start:" + matcher.start() + ", end:" + matcher.end());
        } while(matcher.find());

        return htmlString.replaceAll(HTML_PATTERN, "");
    }
    return htmlString;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HTMLProcessor processor = new HTMLProcessor();
    String output = processor.Process("Some HTML <b id=\"boldtext\">text</b>");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

}

****EDIT****
To complete your requirements, JSoup is absolutely the right way to do. But look like I have to setup a whole project for your requirements. Within the scope of this answer I can only give you some pseudo code.

```
public String processWithJSoup() {
        String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements tags = doc.getAllElements();
        String cleanText = doc.text();

        System.out.println(cleanText);

        for (Element tag : tags) {
            // get node's text
            String nodeText = tag.text();

            // find node's text position in the cleanText for start and end pos

            // get attributes of node

            // create a object to hold the above information

            // push object into an array
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I think I'll use this solution if I don't find a better one, but it isn't foolproof. If I get this: '<b>HTML text</b> and another <b style="color: blue">HTML text</b>' it won't work right

Comment: In that case you can use the position of the tag in the DOM to figure out the correct start & end position.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the before and after HTML as a String then you can use [Apache Diff Builder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/DiffBuilder.html) to get the information you need.